# Advantages of using OpenMP in Z3 nix version

Tags: openmp, z3

I've seen that Z3 can be build from the sources using `--noomp` so it doesn't link with OpenMP.

What is the advantage of using OpenMP. If I use the flag `--noomp` is the solving process gonna be slower?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use OpenMP if you use Z3 from multiple threads within the same process. Otherwise, Z3 is faster without OpenMP. When you enable OpenMP, it uses locks to protect potentially shared memory, but if you never use different threads (NB. all operations on the same context should take place on the same thread, or at least serialized) then these locks are pure overhead.